# Tweepy Error response 400: can anyone tell what is wrong with my code?

Tags: python, twitter, bots, tweepy

I am trying to build a bot in Python, and after fixing my Config module (in which `create_api` is defined) I am encountering some problems while executing the code after `API` is created. Because of the way the error is presented, I am guessing it has something to do with how `check_mentions` is defined, but I wonder what exactly triggers the issue here. I was wondering if anyone could please check the general structure of the code and give me a clue on what it is missing/if something is wrongly defined in there. Thank you in advance!!!
This is the full code as of now:

```
import tweepy
import logging
from config import create_api
import time
import re
from googlesearch import search
import sys
import io


logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger()


api = tweepy.API

def check_mentions(api, since_id):

    logger.info("Collecting info")

    new_since_id = since_id

    for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.mentions_timeline, since_id=since_id).items():

        new_since_id = max(tweet.id, new_since_id)


        if tweet.in_reply_to_status_id is not None:
            in_reply_to_status_id = tweet.id
            status_id = tweet.in_reply_to_status_id
            tweet_u = api.get_status(status_id,tweet_mode='extended')
        

        # remove words between 1 and 3
        shortword = re.compile(r'\W*\b\w{1,3}\b')

        keywords_search = str(shortword.sub('', tweet_u.full_text))

        if keywords_search is not None:

                mystring = search(keywords_search, num_results=500)
        else:
                mystring = search("error", num_results=1)


        output_info=[]
        for word in mystring:
                if "harvard" in word or "cornell" in word or "researchgate" in word or "yale" in word or "rutgers" in word or "caltech" in word or "upenn" in word or "princeton" in word or "columbia" in word or "journal" in word or "mit" in word or "stanford" in word or "gov" in word or "pubmed" in word:
                                output_info.append(word)
                                infostring = ' '.join(output_info)
                else:
                                infostring=None


        if infostring is not None:
                status = "Hi there! This may be what you're looking for" + infostring
                len(status) <= 280
                api.update_status(status, in_reply_to_status_id=tweet.id, auto_populate_reply_metadata=False)

        else:
                status = "Sorry, I cannot help you with that :(. You might want to try again with a distinctly sourced Tweet"
                api.update_status(status, in_reply_to_status_id=tweet.id, auto_populate_reply_metadata=False)

        return new_since_id
    return check_mentions


def main():
    api = create_api()
    since_id = 1 #the last mention you have.
    while True:
        since_id = check_mentions(api, since_id)
        logger.info("Waiting...")
        time.sleep(60)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Config goes as follows (note that `API` effectively shows "created" when the code is executed):

```
# tweepy-bots/bots/config.py
import tweepy
import logging
import os

logger = logging.getLogger()

def create_api():
    consumer_key = os.getenv("CONSUMER_KEY")
    consumer_secret = os.getenv("CONSUMER_SECRET")
    access_token = os.getenv("ACCESS_TOKEN")
    access_token_secret = os.getenv("ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET")

    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
    api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True, 
        wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)
    try:
        api.verify_credentials()
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error("Error creating API", exc_info=True)
        raise e
    logger.info("API created")
    return api
```

I have tried printing things as I defined them and the code seems to work properly in general, except it does not ultimately perform in Twitter for some reason.
Full traceback here:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\maria\OneDrive\Documentos\Lara\Python\Factualbot\botstring23.py", line 85, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\maria\OneDrive\Documentos\Lara\Python\Factualbot\botstring23.py", line 80, in main
    since_id = check_mentions(api, since_id)
  File "C:\Users\maria\OneDrive\Documentos\Lara\Python\Factualbot\botstring23.py", line 28, in check_mentions
    for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.mentions_timeline, since_id=since_id).items():
  File "C:\Users\maria\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\tweepy\cursor.py", line 51, in __next__
    return self.next()
  File "C:\Users\maria\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\tweepy\cursor.py", line 243, in next
    self.current_page = self.page_iterator.next()
  File "C:\Users\maria\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\tweepy\cursor.py", line 132, in next
    data = self.method(max_id=self.max_id, parser=RawParser(), *self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\maria\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\tweepy\binder.py", line 253, in _call
    return method.execute()
  File "C:\Users\maria\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\tweepy\binder.py", line 234, in execute
    raise TweepError(error_msg, resp, api_code=api_error_code)
tweepy.error.TweepError: Twitter error response: status code = 400
```

I think I should also mention that I have tried changing `api.update_status()` to `api.update_status(status="")` which is what I have seen in similar posts, but that has not solved my problem, unfortunately.
Thank you all again!!!!

Answer (score 1):

A 400 status code is a Bad Request error from Twitter's API:

> The request was invalid or cannot be otherwise served. An accompanying error message will explain further. Requests without authentication or with invalid query parameters are considered invalid and will yield this response.

https://developer.twitter.com/en/support/twitter-api/error-troubleshooting

This is likely an issue with your authentication. Without seeing `create_api`, it's impossible to determine the exact cause, but you should check your credentials.

Comment: Hi! Thank you, just added the code for `create_api` on the original post!!